# How can i make BitBucket git clone on my local machine starting from inside directory not from repository directory

Tags: git, bitbucket, directory-structure

On BitBucket my git repository named `demorepo` in that i have such directory structure i.e.

```
demorepo/ 
        /src/..
        /pom.xml
        /readme.txt
```

and i want to check out this repository on my local so that i can do with this command:

```
git clone https://example@bitbucket.org/demouser/demorepo.git
```

when i execute this command then it also creates / starts from `demorepo` directory on my local machine BUT I DON'T WANT THIS `demorepo` ON MY LOCAL MACHINE. I only want files & directories inside this `demorepo` repository.

**HOW I CAN DO THIS?**

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clone to the current directory, you can :

```
git clone https://example@bitbucket.org/demouser/demorepo.git ./
```

But be advised it should be blank (if not, git will tell you there are untracked, etc ...)

You can also name the directory you want to clone to :

```
git clone https://example@bitbucket.org/demouser/demorepo.git myDirectoryName
```